# Hiding back images in iCarouselTypeRotary view for iCarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, carousel, icarousel

I have set images in [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). When I scroll the carousel, it shows images in front and back. I do not want to display images in back. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: have u used sample code of iCarousael then it also provide different switch type from that u can change the type which will not shows image in background

Comment: please explain more thoroughly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change to a custom carousel type, and copy the implementation of iCarouselTypeRotary in your delegate.  Then implement `-carousel:itemAlphaForOffset:` so that items around the back have an alpha of zero.

Comment: Great to hear. If my answer helped, please could you click the tick mark to mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: can you please give more description on this @Simon

Answer (score 8):

You should implement the delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value{
 switch (option)
 {
    case iCarouselOptionVisibleItems:
    {
        return numberOfItemsIntheFront;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of iCarousel, the easiest way to do this is to set view.layer.doubleSided = NO on your carousel item views, or to use the iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces property, like this:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces:
        {
            return NO;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but the views are still visible. If I understand the question correctly, the OP (and myself) are trying to hide the views that are behind the front views.

Comment: Try setting the iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces to NO.

Answer (score 2):

Code below will nicely fade away items that are going to the back. Enjoy.

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    if (option == .Spacing)
    {
        return value * 1.1
    }
    else if (option == .FadeMin)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (option == .FadeMax)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (option == .FadeRange)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution suggested by @NickLockwood but doesn't seem to work :-( I added it to both methods in viewForItemAtIndex & placeholderViewAtIndex. My image size is 115*115 pixels and canvas size is 146*146 pixels. However, setting a return value of 'return value * 0.82f;' under iCarouselOptionSpacing (inside the method valueForOption) did the trick for me.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem than the one asked in the question. I don't see how changing the spacing could affect whether backward-facing items are visible o_O

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way to hide the background images

```
 func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    switch option {
    case .spacing:
        
        return 1.05
        
    case .visibleItems:
        
        return 3

    default:
        return value
```