# how to show iCarousel center view only highlighted other nearest view show some dark

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, icarousel

i am Displaying Images using iCarousel, and its display type is `carousel.type = iCarouselTypeRotary;` all working fine but i need some changes in its displaying UI. I want to display only center view show original alpha and color with highlighted other nearest two view show dark. i did google but not fined any solution. please give me some suggestion or guide how to achieve this.

i explain this using Screenshot Bellow:-

After impliment iCarousel Displaying Images Like this:-

[image]

i want to display like nearest two images view of center imageview  like bellow:-

[image]

please help me on this thank you .

Comment: Heres the solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9379132/1042240

Comment: @AhmedZ. thanks but i m not getting clearly i am using this first time so can u explain in detail please.

Comment: DO you have a method implemented by the name `-carousel:itemAlphaForOffset:` ?

Comment: have you installed newly icarousel project from Github?? the new project has so many extra features.You can check on https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: thank you Nirav let me check :) @AhmedZ. no im not impliment this method but i fount it in .m file

Comment: not getting any luck @NiravPatel bcz i dont knw which method is use for doing like as par my question. :(

Comment: Just put a `return 1.0` for `Alpha = 1` or whatever value you want.

Comment: @NitinGohel .. Use this, it will work as per your need.. Just change the alpha value in the return statement to your own alpha value you need.

Comment: @AhmedZ. can you put plz some code for example plz

Comment: @NitinGohel You just need to put 1 line `return YOUR_ALPHA_VALUE` in the method `-carousel:itemAlphaForOffset:`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30386/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-ahmed-z)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this. The `carousel:itemAlphaForOffset:` answers you've already received are a good approach, but they'll involve doing a bit of maths.

If you have a recent version of `iCarousel`, you can implement this more easily using the options API. Add this method to your `UIViewController` (if you are using the example project it may already be in there and you'll need to modify it):

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel 
     valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option 
        withDefault:(CGFloat)value {

    switch (option) {
        case iCarouselOptionFadeMin:
            return 0;
        case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
            return 0;
        case iCarouselOptionFadeRange:
            return 2;
        default:
            return value;
    }
}
```

You can replace the 2 with a bigger or smaller number to increase or decrease the opacity of the side views. For example, a value of 3 will make them less transparent. A value of 1.5 will make them more transparent. (A value of 1 will make them invisible).